# Does the $\mathsf{TC^0}$ hierarchy collapse?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, complexity-classes, circuit-complexity, bounded-depth

Do we know that the $\mathsf{TC^0}$ hierarchy does not collapse ($\mathsf{TC^0_d} \subsetneq \mathsf{TC^0_{d+1}}$ for all $d$)?

[The Zoo entry for $\mathsf{TC^0}$](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo%3aT#tc0) only mentions the separation between depth 2 and 3.

Also is there a standard reference for the fact that $\mathsf{AC^0_d}$ hierarchy does not collapse?

Comment: A related question would be, how many distinct functions are there in $AC_d^0$ / $TC_d^0$ ? A reasonable lower bound on these quantities would answer your questions. Also a proof of tightness for Hastad's switching lemma would perhaps answer your second question.

Comment: For the second question, I believe it was first proved in [Sipser's STOC '83 paper "Borel sets and circuit complexity"](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=808733). This only gives super-polynomial lower bounds though. The first exponential lower bounds were given by Yao, later improved by Håstad.

Comment: @MCH, did you mean to write $\mathsf{TC^0_d}/\mathsf{AC^0_d}$? Or do you mean the number of equivalence classes of problems in $\mathsf{TC^0_d}$ w.r.t. $\mathsf{AC^0_d}$ reductions?

Comment: What I mean is very simple: How many distinct functions can the class of $AC_d^0$ circuits of size $s$ represent? (We can estimate the number of circuits very easily but we should be careful that some of them may compute the same function.) Once you show that this quantity grows with $d$, you are done.

Comment: @MCH, the / confused me. :)

Comment: Does this question concern uniform TC$^0$ or non-uniform? Also, is there a counting argument showing that the (non-uniform) hierarchy does not collapse?

Comment: @Dilworth, nonuniform. Counting doesn't seem to work, otherwise as I noted below we could then separate $\mathsf{TC^0}$ from $\mathsf{NC^1}$ which is open.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. (So you refer here to uniform TC$^0$, right?)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We know of no good lower bounds (meaning, say, a superpolynomial lower bound for a language in $\mathsf{NEXP}$) for depth 2 threshold circuits (unbounded weights). Depth 3 circuits built from majority gates, i.e. $\mathsf{TC}^0_3$ contains this class, and thus we know no good lower bounds for this class either.

Comment: This answers my question. Thank you Kristoffer.

Comment: As I wrote in the comment above, even if a problem in NEXP is not known to be outside TC$^0_2$, isn't it still possible that the non-uniform TC$^0$ hierarchy is *proper* via a counting argument lower bound?

Comment: Also, may I inquire, how is this consistent with the known exponential lower bounds on TC$_2^0$ and the separation of depth 3 from depth 2 threshold circuits, as reported in the complexity zoo? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Dilworth, I think that is because it is defined using Majority not Threshold.

Comment: Hmm.. what do you mean precisely? Is this related to the note made by Kristoffer about "unbounded weights"?

Answer (score 12):

If I am not making a mistake, it seems that proving that the $\mathsf{TC^0_d}$ hierarchy does not collapse is at least as difficult as separating $\mathsf{NC^1}$ from $\mathsf{TC^0}$:

Let's denote the Boolean Formula Evaluation problem by $BFE$. $BFE$ is complete for $\mathsf{NC^1}$ under $\mathsf{AC^0}$ reductions.

By Manindra Agrawal, Eric Allender, and Steven Rudich, "[Reductions in Circuit Complexity: An Isomorphism Theorem and a Gap Theorem](http://ftp.cs.rutgers.edu/pub/allender/switch3.pdf)", 1999, $BFE$ is complete for $\mathsf{NC^1}$ under $\mathsf{AC^0_2}$ reductions.

Assume $\mathsf{NC^1}=\mathsf{TC^0}$. 
Then $BFE \in \mathsf{TC^0_d}$ for some $d$.
Therefore $\mathsf{NC^1} \subseteq \mathsf{TC^0_{d+2}}$.
Which means that $\mathsf{TC^0} \subseteq \mathsf{TC^0_{d+2}}$.

So for all $d$ we have

> $\mathsf{TC^0} \not\subseteq \mathsf{TC^0_d}$ implies $\mathsf{NC^1} \not\subseteq \mathsf{TC^0_{d+2}}$ and $BFE \notin \mathsf{TC^0_d}$.